Higher homotopy/homology groups of smash product of a space
Let $X$ be a finite CW complex and let $X \wedge X$ denote its smash product. Given the higher homotopy and homology groups $\pi_i(X)$ and $H_i(X)$, is there a simple way to calculate $\pi_i(X \wedge X)$ or $H_i(X \wedge X)$?
For the special case of fundamental groups ($i=1$), there is a formula here. But I'm not aware of a general method for $i \ge 2$, and any method for $H_i(X \wedge X)$. This post is related but the paper(s) mentioned in the discussion there seem to be too technical for me.
If $\pi_i(X) = \pi_i(Y)$ for some $i \ge 2$, and $H_j(X) = H_j(Y)$ for some $j \ge 1$, can I at least say that $\pi_i(X \wedge X) = \pi_i(Y \wedge Y)$ or $H_j(X \wedge X) = H_j(Y \wedge Y)$? Any help is appreciated.
PS: I think the above formula for $\pi_1(X \wedge X)$ does not extend directly for $i \ge 2$, particularly because in general, $\pi_i(X \vee X) \ne \pi_i(X) \ast \pi_i(Y)$ for $i \ge 2$, where $X \vee X$ denotes the wedge sum.

This is pretty much hopeless for homotopy groups (at least, if you want a statement in arbitrary degrees).  For instance, the homotopy groups of $S^1$ are completely known and very simple, but the homotopy groups of $S^1\wedge S^1=S^2$ are not known.  I would expect it is not even true that the homotopy groups of $X$ (up to isomorphism) determine the homotopy groups of $X\wedge X$ (up to isomorphism); for instance, $X=S^2$ and $Y=S^3\times K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ have isomorphic homotopy groups in all degrees but I wouldn't expect $X\wedge X$ and $Y\wedge Y$ to (though I don't see a proof of this off the top of my head).
Homology, on the other hand, is much easier.  You can compute the homology of $X\times X$ by the Künneth formula and then $H_*(X\wedge X)$ is just the quotient of $H_*(X\times X)$ by $H_*(X\times\{*\})\oplus H_*(\{*\}\times X)$.  In particular, with coefficients in a field, there is a natural isomorphism $\tilde{H}_n(X\wedge X)\cong \bigoplus_{i\leq n} \tilde{H}_i(X)\otimes\tilde{H}_{n-i}(X)$.   (Note that knowing the homology of $X$ in a single degree still won't tell you much about the homology of $X\wedge X$ in that degree; the Künneth formula says instead that $H_n(X\wedge X)$ is built out of the $H_i(X)$ for all $i\leq n$.)

@BenSteffan Sorry, that wedge sum was actually supposed to be a product.

Ah, of course; I guess the joke's on me for not questioning the homotopy groups of the wedge sum :) In that case, I can only see a Serre spec. seq. argument: Observe that $Y \wedge Y \cong (S^3 \times S^3) \wedge (K(\mathbb{Z}, 2) \times K(\mathbb{Z}, 2))$ implies that $Y \wedge Y$ is 3-connected and that $\pi_4 Y \wedge Y \cong \mathbb{Z}$, take a fibre sequence $F \to Y \wedge Y \to K(\mathbb{Z}, 4)$ where the last map induces an iso. on $\pi_4$ and consider the resulting Serre spec. seq. [...]

The only group accounting for the convergence to $H_5(Y \wedge Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}^4$ is $E^2_{0, 5} \cong H_5(F)$, so $\mathbb{Z}^4$ is a direct summand of $H_5(F)$, therefore of $\pi_5 Y \wedge Y \cong \pi_5 F$, in contrast to $\pi_5 S^4$ which is finite.

Or just notice that $S^6$ retracts off $Y\wedge Y$ and compare $\pi_6$ for finiteness.
